# How to show percentage instead of ratio in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Handsontable uses numeral.js to format numbers etc.

If the data type is set to numeric and the data format set to 0.00%, handsontable (numeral) formats it nicely in percentage format.  For example,  if the value is 0.5, it is automatically formatted to 50%.

But when the user tries to edit the value, they see 0.5 instead of 50%.  This makes sense, except Excel doesn't behave that way and my users are heavy users of Excel (Excel shows the actual percentage number).  Is there a way to make it show "50" instead of 0.5, while editing? I looked through numeral.js code and found this function formatPercentage that multiplies the number by 100, pads it with the % symbol etc.  It is possible to change the way this function works to make it mimic MS Excel.  But, is there a way to do it without changing numeral.js?

Here is an example of the above (look at the third column - the price column)
http://jsfiddle.net/suk9g9cm/

```
{
    data: "price_usd",
    type: 'numeric',
    format: '0,0.00%',
    language: 'en' //this is the default locale, set up for USD
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem myself and have an untested solution. Let me tell you what's known so far. Handsontable has an Editor and a Renderer. The Editor mimics your data so if you put in 0.5 then whenever you're editing that cell it will display just that. The Renderer is what you see after you leave the cell, in your case you formatted that value so 0.5 will show up as 50%. This value is for show only and as you've pointed out, numeraljs multiplies by 100 and adds a `%`.

What you're looking for, however, is a way to essentially keep the data array as 0.5, but on editing change it to 50, and on rendering, leave as 50%.

Here is a solution:

Using an event on Edit, look at the value of the cell. If it is below 1, multiply by 100 (this will change the real value so we have to adjust later). On afterChange, if the value is greater than 1, divide by 100, otherwise leave (the user might've blanked out and put in 0.5 again so if you don't have this check, the value will go down to 0.005).

Note that in the other case that Excel provides, the user might've entered 50 to begin with so this method will actually modify this and ALWAYS leave the data array with the value 0.5. If this isn't what you wanted then things get harder to do so let's say this is acceptable for now.

That should do the trick though I haven't tested it and there may be edge cases that I'd love to hear about.

Let me know if it worked and in the meantime